# Concatenate mkv files keeping original timestmap with gaps

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, ffmpeg-php

16 days ago I had this problem: [Concatenating mka files but keeping timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63114934/concatenating-mka-files-but-keeping-timestamp/63116333#63116333) which I fixed by using amix, a delay by using `start_pts` from ffprobe.

Today I have a new challenge like this, but with video.

So I have a bunch of mkv videos. Each time a person joins a chat, a mkv is recorded, but if the person refreshes the page a new mkv is created with start_pts and start_time to what it actually is. Also if the meeting started and a person joins after a minute, the start_time is set to 1 minute. I need to merge all those mkv and pad them with blank screen when there is no feed.

Like in the above example, if a person joins after a minute, the first minute is a blank screen. Also if the participant leaves and re-joins after 10 seconds, those 10 seconds are blank again.

Any ideas on how to do that with ffmpeg?

Concrete example of files:

```
0PA84c5c3f412769b311d44b159941b2d22.mkv - start_pts: 742 start_time: 0.742000
2PA73d94e8cb0f41c3002fadd6c04b4a88f.mkv - start_pts: 30761 start_time: 30.761000
3PAcd35e470325618fa8a3fb8bb5a41403e.mkv - start_pts: 50940 start_time: 50.940000
4PAddccde7b8847ecc43d5e8643b7903dba.mkv - start_pts: 69243 start_time: 69.243000
```

The end file would result in a file with length 69.243000, first 0.742 seconds are blank and also the gaps between should also be blank.

So far i've tried:

`ffmpeg -i 0PA84c5c3f412769b311d44b159941b2d22.mkv -i 2PA73d94e8cb0f41c3002fadd6c04b4a88f.mkv -i 3PAcd35e470325618fa8a3fb8bb5a41403e.mkv -i 4PAddccde7b8847ecc43d5e8643b7903dba.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v] [1:v] [2:v] [3:v] concat=n=4:v=1 [v]" -map "[v]" test.mkv`

This works but without those gaps i mentioned.

Comment: Filip, I encountered the same problem in the same scenario as you, have you solved it somehow? I have tried the solution below, but the size of the result gaps is not correct, maybe I am referring to incorrect reference fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the length of the files with ffprobe and calculate the length of the gaps.
Then create those gaps with the `color` filter and concat them between the videos.

Here is the command:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mkv -i 2.mkv -i 3.mkv -filter_complex"\
color=s=1280x720,trim=0:0.742[gap0];\
color=s=1208x720,trim=0:5[gap1];\
color=s=1208x720,trim=0:2[gap2];\
[gap0][0:v][gap1][1:v][gap2][2:v]concat=6:v=1 [v]"\
-map [v] out.mkv
```

Comment: hmm this could work. will try to play it it now. Also do you know how can i resize all videos to the smallest one with concat? Cause for example if user changes webcam and has another resolution, concat complains about it. My idea: loop through all the videos, get the smallest resolution of all of them then all concated videos should be that resolution

Comment: What you could do it using the `scale` filter to resize all the videos. You could make them fit in a box for example like so:    `[0:v]scale=w='if(gt(iw/ih,${w}/${h}),${w},-2)':h='if(gt(iw/ih,${w}/${h}),-2,${h})':eval=init[out]`  with ${w} ${h} your output with and height. This way it doesn't matter what resolution they have, they will be scaled and keep their ratio.

Comment: You then probably also need a `pad` to fill the empty space and the an exact output

Comment: You could also use ffprobe to get the dimensions of the videos beforehand